# NSURLRequest dataTask is returning NSPOSIXErrorDomain, "Protocol error" in iOS 9.3

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am trying to retrieve PDF content from URL which also has authentication challenge. After returning `completionHandler` with user credentials to `URLAuthenticationChallenge`delegate method, I am finally getting below error. This happens only in iOS 9.x versions, but works fine in iOS 10.x.

`Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x7fae60e1e340 [0x1133aaa40]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bbb818161f0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}`

I also tried adding `NSAppTransportSecurity` settings `NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion TLSv1.1` to the info.plist and tried to set `HeaderField's`, but no use.

Comment: We have exactly the same problem when trying to call an https service. Did you solve this?

Comment: anyone have the solution for it ?